# C# Event как использовать

Tags: c#, события, делегаты

Простая консольная программа. Есть хп, и 2 метода (получить урон, или захилится).
Все что я пытаюсь сделать это отоборазить сообщение с помощью ивента в консоли.
Просто хочу понять как работать с ивентами.
Сейчас в консоли ничего не отображается, не понимаю почему. Вроде подписался, вроде методы прокинул...Помогите плз.
Разбил на 3 класса.

1. Program
2. Health
3. EventClass

**...Event...**

```
public class EventClass
{
    public delegate void MonitorHp(int a);
    public event MonitorHp HealEvent;

    public void HealMethod(int a)
    {
        HealEvent?.Invoke(a);
    }
}
```

**...Health...**

```
public class Health
{
    public int Heal;

    public Health(int health)
    {
        Heal = health;
    }

    public void GetHeal(int a)
    {
        Heal += a;
    }

    public void GetDamage(int a)
    {
        Heal -= a;
    }
}
```

**Program**

```
class Program
{
    public static EventClass eventClass = new EventClass();
    public static Health health = new Health(100);
    static void Main()
    {
        eventClass.HealEvent += EventClass_HealEvent;
        health.GetDamage(20);
        health.GetHeal(2);
    }

    private static void EventClass_HealEvent(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(health.Heal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Представьте новостную ленту, где вы по нажатию кнопки делаете подписку на новостей, а когда будет выпущена новая новость, все те, кто подписался на это событие, получат уведомление. Вот написав `.HealEvent += EventClass_HealEvent` - вы подписались на это событие, вы можете подписаться на него во множестве мест сразу, и все они будут получать обновления. Теперь внимание, как вызывается оповещение? Наверно `HealEvent?.Invoke(a);`, правильно? Да... А вот где вы это вызываете? Я вижу создание класса, вижу подписку, но не вижу вызова `HealMethod(int a)` (в котором вы оповещаете подписчиков).

Comment: Не знаю как вам поставить лайк тут. Но хочу сказать спасибо!  Я вызвал его в program и все работает. Но честно говоря принимаемое значение не знал откуда брать и просто для теста поставил 1. А оно работает ))) 
public static EventClass eventClass = new EventClass();
public static Health health = new Health(100);
static void Main()
{
    eventClass.HealEvent += EventClass_HealEvent;
    health.GetDamage(20);
    health.GetHeal(2);
    eventClass.HealMethod(2);
}

private static void EventClass_HealEvent(int a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(health.Heal);
}